# Switch-case statement destroys rendered components

Tags: reactjs

I have following problem:
I'm using *nba-react-logos* package and it works fine, until I'm trying to determine, which component should be returned. Here is my component which determine which component from package should be rendered:

```
    export const TEAMS_LOGOS = {
    [TEAM_76ERS]: Logos.PHI,
    [TEAM_RAPTORS]: Logos.TOR,
    [TEAM_TIMBERWOLVES]: Logos.MIN,
    [TEAM_BUCKS]: Logos.MIL,
    [TEAM_HORNETS]: Logos.CHA,
    [TEAM_NUGGETS]: Logos.DEN,
    [TEAM_PISTONS]: Logos.DET,
    [TEAM_MAGIC]: Logos.ORL,
    [TEAM_PELICANS]: Logos.NOP,
    [TEAM_LAKERS]: Logos.LAL,
    [TEAM_THUNDER]: Logos.OKC,
    [TEAM_MAVERICKS]: Logos.DAL,
    [TEAM_KINGS]: Logos.SAC,
    [TEAM_BLAZERS]: Logos.POR,
    [TEAM_JAZZ]: Logos.UTA,
    [TEAM_HAWKS]: Logos.ATL,
    [TEAM_WARRIORS]: Logos.GSW,
    [TEAM_SUNS]: Logos.PHX,
    [TEAM_NETS]: Logos.BKN,
    [TEAM_KNICKS]: Logos.NYK,
    [TEAM_WIZARDS]: Logos.WAS,
    [TEAM_SPURS]: Logos.SAS,
    [TEAM_BULLS]: Logos.CHI,
    [TEAM_CELTICS]: Logos.BOS,
    [TEAM_ROCKETS]: Logos.HOU,
    [TEAM_PACERS]: Logos.IND,
    [TEAM_CLIPPERS]: Logos.LAC,
    [TEAM_CAVALIERS]: Logos.CLE,
    [TEAM_GRIZZLIES]: Logos.MEM,
    [TEAM_HEAT]: Logos.MIA
}
```

There is also functional component, which is used in my app:

```
export default function PickTeam({team, size}) {
    const Found = Constants.TEAMS_LOGOS[team];
    return Found ? <Found size={size} /> : <div />;
}
```

The problem is that if I want to render those components in many components on the same page - I'm losing some colors. I don't know if problem is with my code or maybe with this package. I can see that if i render them in component, they look good for 1-2 seconds, until my http-request based component loads - then this color dissapearance appers.

**EDIT**

Ok, so here is more specified description. I have following code:

This is component which determine which team logo has to be rendered. Props are generated from axios request to my server.

```
    export default function TeamScoreBox(props) {
    return (
        <div className="mainScoreBarTeam">
            <PickTeam team={props.teamAbbreviation} size={100}/> 
        </div>
    );
}
```

Next one is just for test, it is HomeComponent, and it is rendered without any request:

```
    export const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div><Logos.BOS></Logos.BOS><Logos.PHX></Logos.PHX><Logos.BOS></Logos.BOS><Logos.PHI></Logos.PHI><Logos.PHI></Logos.PHI>
        <PickTeam team={"PHI"} size={100}/></div>
    );
}
```

And now here are results:

1. [First 1-2 seconds after refreshing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d5cG.png)
2. [After geting data to games bar (on top)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFuHx.png)

And this is what I have a problem with. As you can see, for example Boston Celtics logo (the green one) loses black color, 76ers (logo with red seven and blue six) loses red color.

**EDIT v2**

I made some corrections as @emi suggested, but it didn't help.

So there's full code of my components:

App.js:

```
    export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="background">
      <ContextProvider>
        <Router>
          <Navigation />
          <Scores />
          <div className="content">
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route path="/players/:id" exact={true} component={PlayerStats} />
            <Route path="/players" exact={true} component = {Players} />
            <ProtectedRoute path='/logout' />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </ContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

On every page I have navigation and scores, so move to Scores component:

Scores.js:

```
    export default function Scores() {
    const [matches, setMatches] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://localhost:44324/apidata/todaygames',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
            },
        }).then((res) => {
            
            setMatches(res.data);
            setLoading(false);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }, []);

    
        return !loading 
        ?
        (
            <Row className="mainScoreBar">
                {matches.map((key) => {
                    return (
                        <Col key={key.homeTeam + key.visitorTeam} sm={4} style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
                            <Score gameData={key} />
                        </Col>
                    );
                })}
            </Row>
        )
        : <Loading />
}
```

Score.js:

```
    export default function Score(props) {
    const [game, setGame] = useState(props.gameData);

    return (
        <Card className="mainScoreBarItem">
            <Row className="align-items-center h-100">
                <Col >
                    <TeamScoreBox
                        teamName={game.homeTeam}
                        teamAbbreviation={game.homeTeamAbbreviation}
                    />
                </Col>
                <Col >
                    <div className="mainScoreBarResult">{game.homeTeamScore}:{game.visitorTeamScore}</div>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <TeamScoreBox
                        teamName={game.visitorTeam}
                        teamAbbreviation={game.visitorTeamAbbreviation}
                    />
                </Col>
            </Row>

        </Card>
    )
}
```

And TeamScoreBox.js:

```
    export default function TeamScoreBox(props) {
    return (
        <div className="mainScoreBarTeam">
            <PickTeam team={props.teamAbbreviation} size={100}/> 
        </div>
    );
}
```

So route "/" should render Navigation, Scores and (mentioned in first edit) Home controller.

My axios response:

```
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
homeTeam: "Golden State Warriors"
homeTeamAbbreviation: "GSW"
homeTeamScore: 100
visitorTeam: "Boston Celtics"
visitorTeamAbbreviation: "BOS"
visitorTeamScore: 105
__proto__: Object
1:
homeTeam: "Los Angeles Lakers"
homeTeamAbbreviation: "LAL"
homeTeamScore: 99
visitorTeam: "Sacramento Kings"
visitorTeamAbbreviation: "SAC"
visitorTeamScore: 97
__proto__: Object
2:
homeTeam: "Minnesota Timberwolves"
homeTeamAbbreviation: "MIN"
homeTeamScore: 116
visitorTeam: "Washington Wizards"
visitorTeamAbbreviation: "WAS"
visitorTeamScore: 137
__proto__: Object
3:
homeTeam: "Houston Rockets"
homeTeamAbbreviation: "HOU"
homeTeamScore: 111
visitorTeam: "Indiana Pacers"
visitorTeamAbbreviation: "IND"
visitorTeamScore: 102
__proto__: Object
4:
homeTeam: "Orlando Magic"
homeTeamAbbreviation: "ORL"
homeTeamScore: 111
visitorTeam: "San Antonio Spurs"
visitorTeamAbbreviation: "SAS"
visitorTeamScore: 109
__proto__: Object
5:
homeTeam: "Oklahoma City Thunder"
homeTeamAbbreviation: "OKC"
homeTeamScore: 127
visitorTeam: "Philadelphia 76ers"
visitorTeamAbbreviation: "PHI"
visitorTeamScore: 119
__proto__: Object
6:
homeTeam: "Memphis Grizzlies"
homeTeamAbbreviation: "MEM"
homeTeamScore: 107
visitorTeam: "Utah Jazz"
visitorTeamAbbreviation: "UTA"
visitorTeamScore: 106
__proto__: Object
7:
homeTeam: "Charlotte Hornets"
homeTeamAbbreviation: "CHA"
homeTeamScore: 109
visitorTeam: "Detroit Pistons"
visitorTeamAbbreviation: "DET"
visitorTeamScore: 106
```

Comment: To make your code cleaner (and probably more efficient if you create the array aoutside the function, or when optimized by the JS engine), your big `switch/case` block code can be changed into an associative array: `const relations = {[Constants.TEAM_76ERS]: Logos.PHI, ....}; const Found = relations[team]; return Found ? <Found size={size} /> : <div/>`

Comment: Based on the code you have provided, there is nothing which changes colors anywhere, not even any color is changed or shown at all. I think you will need to reformulate your question to get some help.

Comment: @emi I've updated my post, so I hope my problem now is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken a look into [`nba-react-logos` source code](https://github.com/ChrisKatsaras/React-NBA-Logos). It uses SVG directly from React and sometimes uses SVG IDs. I've seen at least one non-existing reference, and multiple definitions with the same ID across logos. If this could be an issue, but still works on initial render, we can minimize errors by memoizing the component:

```js
export default React.memo(function PickTeam({team, size}) {
    const Found = Constants.TEAMS_LOGOS[team];
    return Found ? <Found size={size} /> : <div />;
})
```

#### Edit

Example of strange/unoptimized SVG code in [`nba-react-logos`](https://github.com/ChrisKatsaras/React-NBA-Logos/blob/master/src/Icons/bos.js):

```js
      <defs>
        <path id="A" d="M0 0h93.554v104H0z" />
        <path id="B" d="M0 0h93.554v104H0z" />
        <path
          id="C"
          d="M93.554 48.9c0-12.494-..."
        />
      </defs>
      <g transform="translate(25 20)" fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
        <path
          d="M99.87 52.054c0-13.33-..."
          fill="#fefefe"
        />
        <g transform="translate(3 3)">
          <mask id="D" fill="#fff">
            <use xlinkHref="#A" />
          </mask>
          <use xlinkHref="#C" fill="#fff" mask="url(#D)" />
          <mask id="E" fill="#fff">
            <use xlinkHref="#B" />
          </mask>
          <use xlinkHref="#C" fill="#061922" mask="url(#E)" />
        </g>
```

- `#A` and `#B` are exactly the same, so `#D` and `#E` are also exactly the same. So first `use` in this `g` is overlapped by the second one. Also, those IDs are equally used in other Logos.

In order to debug this (never do that to fix things!), can you manually edit your `./node_modules/nba-react-logos` source code and modify the IDs, so they are unique across the entire document? For example, change `id="A"` to `id="A_BOS"` and `"#A"` to `"#A_BOS"` (and the same for `B`, `C`, `D` and `E`).

Once changed, ensure the changes are shown in your rendered page and see if it fixes this logo. If it does, you can complete the [bug report you opened there](https://github.com/ChrisKatsaras/React-NBA-Logos/issues/3), even with a pull request if you fill comfortable (and to avoid waiting for the author to respond by using your own copy of the repo instead of the official).

Comment: Nope, still nothing. I'm afraid that I will have to find something else to do this logos, because I really don't know the reason.

Comment: Added another way to try to debug this.

Comment: Finally! Seems to be correct answer. I've replaced IDs in some logos (especially those, which was bugged) and it works for now. Really apriciate your help and thanks for your time! :)

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to complete the bug report and PR to help yourself and others!

Comment: @axern Please, also up vote the answer ;)

Comment: Hi everyone! It's Chris Katsaras (the creator of react-nba-logos) thanks for having this discussion and identifying an issue with IDs! I made a PR and updated the package to reflect the suggestion here.
However, I want to point out one thing about @emi comment. The SVG code isn't optimized as that is the dev file which is meant to be more readable. A more efficient version is created when running my prod script which is what is published to the repo. I realized recently that I accidentally published both dev and prod versions but that should be fixed now!

All the best,
Chris

Comment: The latest version - as of writing this comment - is now V1.1.0 :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `OtherFunctions.pickTeam` could be written as a functional component:

```js
const relations = {
  [Constants.TEAM_76ERS]: Logos.PHI,
  // etc...
};
export function PickTeam({team, size}) {
  const Found = relations[team];
  return Found ? <Found size={size} /> : <div/>
}
```

Then, you use it as any other component:

```js
export default function TeamScoreBox(props) {
  return (
    <div className="mainScoreBarTeam">
      <OtherFunctions.PickTeam team={props.teamAbbreviation} size={100} /> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

And your `Home` component, using new `PickTeam` and simplifying components without children:

```js
export const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Logos.BOS/><Logos.PHX/><Logos.BOS/><Logos.PHI/><Logos.PHI/>
      <OtherFunctions.PickTeam team={"PHI"} size={100} /> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

This will increase performance, legibility and maintainability.

Your colors problem is still independent from the code you posted in your question, but may benefit from the examples posted in this answer. Please, test it and, if still not working, add relevant code during and around the AXIOS call, which looks like some classes/statuses/props are handled there. Also, if relevant, post what your server responds to that request.

Comment: I did it and it didn't solve my problem. I've updated post once again.

Comment: Your question still references old version in the 3 first code blocks. Please, edit it to prevent confuse new comers (or ourselves in the future).

Answer (score 1):

The `loading` logic does not seems ok: you should assign `true` just before the `fetch` and assign `false` on the final `then`:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://localhost:44324/apidata/todaygames',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
            },
        }).then((res) => {
            setMatches(res.data);
            setLoading(false);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }, []);
```

#### Edit

Your `loading` logic is still buggy: you want to show data while it's loading, and show `<Loading/>` when not. Try this, which uses ternary operator:

```js
    // Invert condition
    return !loading
         ? (
            <Row className="mainScoreBar">
                {matches.map((key) => {
                    return (
                        <Col key={key.homeTeam + key.visitorTeam} sm={4} style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
                            <Score gameData={key} />
                        </Col>
                    );
                })}
            </Row>
         )
         : <Loading/>
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything.

Comment: Do you have any other advices?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to change it here, but it doesn't matter - if i remove all "loading" functionality - I face same problem. Also I got the same situation in component with list of players, but there is situation, when I filter my results, logos starts to render properly. But there is one condition - Scores components has to be disabled. I think there is something to do with this Logos components picking...